# Pass Data to Laravel Controller through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to read data from a select row datatable and post the data through AJAX to my Laravel Controller. but something is wrong here. when i die and dump request all "dd(request()->all());" in my controller i only get the token value and data is empty. i dont know what i'm doing wrong. i'm new to jquery please help.

```
function AJAXCallCancelSimsByAPN(data) {
  var url = "/tools/sim/cancel";
  var type = "POST";

  jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content')
    }
  });

  console.log(data);

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: {
      "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content'),
      "data": data
    },
    beforeSend: function () {},
    success: function (data) {
      try {
        //console.log(data);        

      } catch (err) {
        alert("Error running JS code from module: AJAXCallCancelSimsByAPN");
      }
    },
    error: function (url, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("url: " + url + " error: " + jqXHR.responseText + " status: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function () {}
  });
}
```

Controller

```
public function cancelSIMS(Request $request)
    {
       dd(request()->all());

        //
    }
```

Output

```
array:1 [
  "_token" => "7wc63lIYESIYNCVHYUe3YAI5KSxo1nqvTgtCr"
]
```

Comment: can we see your data which you passing as parameter ?

Comment: [apnID: "67", cancelDate: "02/05/2019", sims: Array(1)]

Comment: Have you turned your javascript data into the json ? I mean did you use JSON.stringify() method ?

Comment: Yes i tried that but still doesnt work

Comment: Can you set contentType attribute as "application/json" and try again ?

Comment: No Joy. I still get an empty response

Comment: on your console.log() you got "[apnID: "67", cancelDate: "02/05/2019", sims: Array(1)]" ???

Comment: Yes that's what i get on console.log()

Comment: can you share screenshot about request and payload ? Because request seems normal

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing your data before sending it :

```
var serialized = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and

```
data: {
  "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content'),
  "data": serialized
},
```

How does that compute ?

Comment: This is what i get  " data "  => " [ ] "

Comment: On an unrelated note, [jQuery recommends](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to set the header in the .ajax() call and not with .ajaxSetup() because ajaxSetup sets the parameters for all following ajax calls.